# Oracle Sql Developer Export Specific Tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using the 'Oracle Sql Developer' and I need to export the data and table structure of a specific table out of hundreds in one database. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Here's a link that might help you: http://helpdeskgeek.com/databases/an-introduction-to-oracle-sql-developer-part-iv/  Be sure to check out part 1 and further as well: http://helpdeskgeek.com/databases/oracle-sql-developer-tutorial/

Comment: Thank You for responding so quickly. I have tried this approach, but when I get to the part about specifying objects and data, nothing shows up. Then if I just continue it starts exporting everything in the database. any ideas?

Comment: Does your user own any tables? Perhaps you need to log in as the table owner.